# Use of special symbol in struts2

Tags: struts2, struts

```
<s:set name="Name" value="%{'Gyan'}" />

<s:if test="%{#Name=='Singh'}">You Working with--

<div><s:property value="%{#Name}" /></div>

<div>Your Name is Gyan</div>

</s:if>
```

can any body tell me that what is the role of % and # symbol in above code ?

Answer (score 2):

These are the various way to access dats being places by Struts2 in the value stack as well in other scope.
`%` is way to access or tell Struts2 that you want to resolve this particular expression against the value stored in the Value-stack, this is a way to force OGNL, a build in data-conversion and transfer mechanism to come to play.

To access the attributes values stored in Session, Application  scope etc we use `#` which is an indicator to Struts2 that from where we want to access the values.

I suggest you to please refer official OGNL documents for more and clear details about this.

- [OGNL-Basics](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/ognl-basics.html).
- [OGNL](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/ognl.html)